# Android Firebase Sorting

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app. I have a Firebase database with a bunch of products, each of them has a rating. I am displaying them in a ListView but want to sort them by their rating. Do I need to save them differently to get this to work ?

```
  private ListView mTopRatedList;
    ArrayList<String> mAllBeers = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference Reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Beers");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_rated);

        mTopRatedList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.topRatedList);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mAllBeers);
        mTopRatedList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.clear();


        Reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayAdapter.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //arrayAdapter.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Beers beers = snapshot.getValue(Beers.class);
                    String beerClass = beers.getmName();
                    Float beerRating = beers.getmRating();
                    //Collections.sort()
                    arrayAdapter.add(beerClass+ "User Rating is " + beerRating);

                }
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of your code, each of your beers has a `rating` property in the database.

In that case you can show the beers ordered by rating by doing:

```
Reference.orderByChild("rating").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

A few notes:

- This will show the beers in *ascending* order of their rating, so with the lowest value first. If you want to show the highest rated beer first, Firebase does *not* have a built-in operator for descending sort. So you'll have to work around that by either reversing the results in your client-side code, or by including an inverted rating in the database too for this purpose. In the latter case you'd sort on the inverted rating, and then display the regular rating.
- For this to work correctly it is important that the `rating` value is a number, and not stored as a string. When stored as a string it may work for values up to 9, but after that you'll run into cases where numerical ordering differs from the lexicographical ordering that Firebase will use for strings.
- Please never leave `onCancelled` empty as it hides potential problems. Its minimal implementation is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i did try that method but it orders them in descending. Is there a way to do it ascending by value ?

Comment: I just hit submit on an update about that. Btw: it'd be nice to see your best try in the question in the future.

Comment: Thanks will do that in the future. My rating value is stored as a float. I will look into how to get the rating changed in the database now. Thanks for your detailed reply :)

Comment: I found a way around the order i called a Collections.reverse(mAllBeers); To reverse the order of the listview i don't need to select elements on this list so it works perfect. Will do thanks again

Comment: Good to hear. That's the "reversing the results in your client-side code" in the first note in my answer, and when you're creating your own adapter its usually the easiest. :)